# Simple controller functional test failing

Tags: symfony, phpunit

This is my first Controller unit test for Symfony2. Copying as fully as I can from the Docs, I'm simply asserting the inclusion of some text.

```
use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Test\WebTestCase;

class AdviseeControllerTest extends WebTestCase
{
    public function testCreatePageContainsContent()
    {
        $client = static::createClient();

        $crawler = $client->request('GET', '/create/adviseeSet');

        $this->assertGreaterThan(
            0,
            $crawler->filter('html:contains("Name")')->count()
        );

    }
}
```

My route is as follows:

```
advisee_set_create:
    pattern: /create/adviseeSet
    defaults: { _controller: AcademicsBundle:Advisee:create }
```

This test fails, along with any other test that asserts the inclusion of any kind of content. is there something I'm ignorant about how $client->request() or $crawler->filter() works that copying from the Default example is not passing? My Test lives in AcademicsBundle > Tests > AdviseeControllerTest.php

Outputted message(with both --verbose and -debug) is:

```
...\AcademicsBundle\Tests\Controller\AdviseeControllerTest::testCreatePageContainsContent
Failed asserting that 0 is greater than 0.
```

Comment: What's the error message while running your test?

Comment: @Javad I edited my question to include this

Comment: Make sure the `/create/adviseeSet` is true. Make sure your test class in the namespace of `namespace Academics\AcademicsBundle\Tests\Controller;`

Comment: my namespace is correct, compared with some passing entity unit tests.

Comment: Do you have anything in the construct of you test class? Have you cleared your cache?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My crawler needed to follow redirects, so I added:

```
    $client->followRedirect();
```

By testing

```
    $content = $client->getResponse()->getContent();
    $this->assertEquals('shmee', $content);
```

I was able to get a much more helpful failure message

```
Failed asserting that two strings are equal.
--- Expected
+++ Actual
@@ @@
-'shmee'
+'<!DOCTYPE html>
+<html>
+    <head>
+        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
+        <meta http-equiv="refresh" content="1;url=http://localhost/create/adviseeSet" />
+
+        <title>Redirecting to http://localhost/create/adviseeSet</title>
+    </head>
+    <body>
+        Redirecting to <a href="http://localhost/create/adviseeSet">http://localhost/create/adviseeSet</a>.
+    </body>
+</html>'
```

And I saw the shortened path in the attempted redirect.

Comment: Hi, I'm having this same problem but I'm on a virtual host. How did you add that followRedirect() ? 
Like this ?
`$crawler = $client->request('GET', '/blog/');
 $crawler->followRedirect();`